# NameError: name 'func' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Does anyone see why I'm getting a "func undefined" error here? Everything looks correct to me.

```
// dictutil.py
def func(L):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(L)):
        d[i] = L[i]
    return d
```

// Python command-line prompt:

```
import dictutil (attempt to load dictutil.py)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try to access `func` without qualifying it? `dictutil.func`

Comment: Qualifying doesn't help:>>> dictutil.func(['a','b'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your code is correct, you have not imported `func` into your namespace (which is what the NameError is trying to tell you).

You have options:

1) import `func()` into your namespace on the import:

```
from dictutil import func
```

2) qualify calls to `func()` by referencing the module that contains the function:

```
dictutil.func()
```

Generally, you can view what's in your locally scoped namespace (meaning that it can be called directly) by using the `dir()` method:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'dictutil', 'readline', 'rlcompleter']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access func like:

```
import dictutil
dictutil.func()
```